# How can i get the html of the page?

Tags: c#

Here is the code I use to perform a web request. I'm getting all of the HTML except for the comments section in the URL.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(
  "http://u-handbag.typepad.com/uhandblog/2013/11/choosing-bag-fabrics.html#comment-6a00d8341c574653ef019b022fc96f970d"
);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
htl = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I don't really know to be honest, but wouldn't the javascript modify the output. Maybe that's why you have different data.

Answer (score 1):

Use this chunk of code. Variable result should have the html code.

```
 System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
 string result = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
```

Comment: i Do this but failed ...

Comment: I tried the code I posted. It works in my machine. I'm getting everything including the comments section. Make sure your URL really points to something. Please check your URL.

Comment: dear every thing correct i think the comments section of the url loading form ajax or may be jquery and my request get the html before ajaxx/jquery request ....is any way to get the html after ajax/jquery request ???

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem. Anyways, I checked the URL and the comments section had links to another URL, which means yeah it does use Ajax to load the comments. If you want to get the html source of the comments, manipulating the original URL like searching for the comment URLs and getting the source might be a good idea. I actually did something like this before so I know it works. I'm just not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: yeah exactly thats my problem how to solve it ?

Comment: If you want to get the html source of the comments, manipulating the original URL like searching for the comment URLs and getting the source might be a good idea.

Comment: i dnt get what you say ???

Answer (score 1):

Getting HTML code from a website page. You can use code like this.

```
string urlAddress = "http://u-handbag.typepad.com/uhandblog/2013/11/choosing-bag-fabrics.html#comment-6a00d8341c574653ef019b022fc96f970d";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader readStream = null;
  if (response.CharacterSet == null)
    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
  else
    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
  string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
  response.Close();
  readStream.Close();
}
```

or better to use `WebClient`

```
        using System.Net;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://u-handbag.typepad.com/uhandblog/2013/11/choosing-bag-fabrics.html#comment-6a00d8341c574653ef019b022fc96f970d");
        }
```

Comment: Dear i apply this code but failed to get (comments section(in the above url ) )..........

Comment: in my machine it works. What is the error you are getting

Comment: i am unable to get html the comments section in the url..please help me..?